# apache not servce media file django when debug =false

Tags: django, apache

I use Linux VPS to run my application for android API
and use apache web server when the debug is true my app work completely, but when debug is false I can't access my media file and get an error 
this is my apache conf :
[image]

and this is my setting.py:
[image]

and this is my media location:
[image] 
where is wrong and how to fix it debug false in my production and serve media file completely

Answer (score 0):

you should change your static directory permission.
now Apache don't have access to your file.
somting like`chmod 777 -R static` can help you.